# TS7016: "Could not find a declaration file for module" even though declarations are available

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm writing an app in typescript and I'd like to use the [@cyclonedx/cyclonedx-library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cyclonedx/cyclonedx-library) package (v1.7.0 as of today).

The problem is, tsc throws the following error. FWIW, the import statement was copied straight from the package's [typescript example](https://github.com/CycloneDX/cyclonedx-javascript-library/blob/main/examples/node-typescript/example.ts).

```
src/enhancedCycloneDxSchema.ts:4:22 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '@cyclonedx/cyclonedx-library'. 'C:/workspace/fv-sbom-generator/node_modules/@cyclonedx/cyclonedx-library/dist.node/index.node.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/cyclonedx__cyclonedx-library` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@cyclonedx/cyclonedx-library';`

4 import * as CDX from "@cyclonedx/cyclonedx-library";
```

I've researched this error and here on SO as well as elsewhere, the solutions always fall into one of the following categories:

- The user had to install typings separately, as suggested by the error message.
- No typings were available for the package, so a module was manually declared for the package (either empty just to silence the compiler or with declarations inside).
- The error was disabled altogether in `tsconfig.json` with `"noImplicitAny": false`.

The thing is, this package **does** provide type declarations, starting in version 1.7.0 they are located under `node_modules/@cyclonedx/cyclonedx-library/dist.d` and the package.json contains the line `"types": "./dist.d/index.node.d.ts"`.

I must admit I'm a typescript beginner, so I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2021",
    "module": "Node16",
    "moduleResolution": "Node16",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```

Comment: please refer to the project's official support channel: https://github.com/CycloneDX/cyclonedx-javascript-library/issues

Comment: I was going by the assumption that this was not an error on the part of the library authors but my configuration which might have thrown the same error with any other library.But you might be right that that’s a better channel for my problem.